# Homework: Implementing Karp-Rabin; For the hash values modulo q, explain why it is a bad idea to use q as a power of 2?

Tags: algorithm, hash, bioinformatics, biopython, rabin-karp

I have a two-fold homework problem, Implement Karp-Rabin and run it on a test file and the second part:

> 2. For the hash values modulo q, explain why it is a bad idea to use q as a power of 2. Can you construct a terrible example e.g. for q=64
>      and n=15?

This is my implementation of the algorithm:

```
def karp_rabin(text, pattern):
    # setup
    alphabet = 'ACGT'
    d = len(alphabet)
    n = len(pattern)
    d_n = d**n
    q = 2**32-1
    m = {char:i for i,char in enumerate(alphabet)}
    positions = []

    def kr_hash(s):
        return sum(d**(n-i-1) * m[s[i]] for i in range(n))

    def update_hash():
        return d*text_hash + m[text[i+n-1]] - d_n * m[text[i-1]]

    pattern_hash = kr_hash(pattern)
    for i in range(0, len(text) - n + 1):
        text_hash = update_hash() if i else kr_hash(text[i:n])
        if pattern_hash % q == text_hash % q and pattern == text[i:i+n]:
            positions.append(i)

    return ' '.join(map(str, positions))
```

...The second part of the question is referring to this part of the code/algo:

```
    pattern_hash = kr_hash(pattern)
    for i in range(0, len(text) - n + 1):
        text_hash = update_hash() if i else kr_hash(text[i:n])
        # the modulo q used to check if the hashes are congruent
        if pattern_hash % q == text_hash % q and pattern == text[i:i+n]:
            positions.append(i)
```

I don't understand why it would be a bad idea to use q as a power of 2. I've tried running the algorithm on the test file provided(which is the genome of ecoli) and there's no discernible difference.

I tried looking at the formula for how the hash is derived (I'm not good at math) trying to find some common factors that would be really bad for powers of two but found nothing. I feel like if q is a power of 2 it should cause a lot of clashes for the hashes so you'd need to compare strings a lot more but I didn't find anything along those lines either.

I'd really appreciate help on this since I'm stumped. If someone wants to point out what I can do better in the first part (code efficiency, readability, correctness etc.) I'd also be thrilled to hear your input on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem if q divides some power of d, because then only a few characters contribute to the hash. For example in your code d=4, if you take q=64 only the last three characters determine the hash (d**3 = 64).

I don't really see a problem if q is a power of 2 but gcd(d,q) = 1.

Your implementation looks a bit strange because instead of

```
if pattern_hash % q == text_hash % q and pattern == text[i:i+n]:
```

you could also use

```
if pattern_hash == text_hash and pattern == text[i:i+n]:
```

which would be better because you get fewer collisions.

Comment: ok I looked into this and this has to be what my teacher is referring to... I will expand on this for my answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) has among its properties that its polynomial hash quickly becomes zero when a power of 2 is the hash module, for whatever polynomial base (`d`). So if you will try to search a short Thue-Morse sequence in a longer one, you will have a great lot of hash collisions.

For example, your code, slightly adapted:

```
def karp_rabin(text, pattern):
    # setup
    alphabet = '01'
    d = 15
    n = len(pattern)
    d_n = d**n
    q = 32
    m = {char:i for i,char in enumerate(alphabet)}
    positions = []

    def kr_hash(s):
        return sum(d**(n-i-1) * m[s[i]] for i in range(n))

    def update_hash():
        return d*text_hash + m[text[i+n-1]] - d_n * m[text[i-1]]

    pattern_hash = kr_hash(pattern)
    for i in range(0, len(text) - n + 1):
        text_hash = update_hash() if i else kr_hash(text[i:n])
        if pattern_hash % q == text_hash % q : #and pattern == text[i:i+n]:
            positions.append(i)

    return ' '.join(map(str, positions))

print(karp_rabin('0110100110010110100101100110100110010110011010010110100110010110', '0110100110010110'))
```

outputs a lot of positions, although only three of then are proper matches.

Note that I have dropped the `and pattern == text[i:i+n]` check. Obviously if you restore it, the result will be correct, but also it is obvious that the algorithm will do much more work checking this additional condition than for other `q`. In fact, because there are so many collisions, the whole idea of algorithm becomes not working: you could almost as effectively wrote a simple algorithm that checks every position for a match.

---

Also note that your implementation is quite strange. The whole idea of polynomial hashing is to take the modulo operation *each time* you compute the hash. Otherwise your `pattern_hash` and `text_hash` are very big numbers. In other languages this might mean arithmetic overflow, but in Python this will invoke big integer arithmetic, which is slow and once again loses the whole idea of the algorithm.

Comment: so I should take the modulo in both kr_hash and update_hash? Don't I need the dividend text_hash for the update_hash? What does the first part of update_hash mean if text_hash is just the remainder of the previous update_hash calculations, i.e. what does d*text_hash mean?

Comment: @ÞórÓðinsson, yes, the best way to do is to take modulo after _every_ operation with hash. This is just [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). I think this wikipedia link will have answers on your questions, or just read more on that topic.